# How can you extract strings from a merged column based off of previously extracted strings in separate columns in R?

Tags: r, string, parsing, dataframe, split

I have been parsing a single merged column containing multiple categories of  information into separated columns for the unique categories. I have been using stringr for identifying category patterns that need to be separated out of the single column.

I was able to separate all category information that contained unique, repetitive, and identifiable patterns but am now left with the task of extracting category information that follows no obvious extract-able pattern.

Here is a basic example setup:

```
col1 <- c("a1 b1 apple c1","a2 b2 fruit c2","a3 b3 bunny(1) c3","a4 b4 x5  c4")
col2 <- c("b1","b2","b3","b4")
col3 <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4")
col4 <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4")

dat <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

So now I need to extract the term in the third position of `dat$col1`.

```
>dat$col5
 apple
 fruit
 bunny(1)
 x5
```

I would like to do this based off of the previously extracted strings in `dat[,c(2,3,4)]`. This is a very basic example and I am trying to find the most reliable method for extracting data that may not fall evenly in the same position of `dat$col1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `Map` with `setdiff` which will capture the word of `col1` not found in `col2, 3, 4`.

```
v1 <- unlist(Map(setdiff, strsplit(dat$col1, ' '), 
                          strsplit(apply(dat[,-1], 1, paste, collapse = ' '), ' ')))
dat$col5 <- v1[v1 != '']
dat
#               col1 col2 col3 col4     col5
#1    a1 b1 apple c1   b1   a1   c1    apple
#2    a2 b2 fruit c2   b2   a2   c2    fruit
#3 a3 b3 bunny(1) c3   b3   a3   c3 bunny(1)
#4      a4 b4 x5  c4   b4   a4   c4       x5
```

Note that your variables need to be characters (not factors) for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation, similar in spirit to @Sotos' idea to use setdiff, using the `purrr` package. Note - I'm pretty new to `purrr`, so there is likely a more efficient way to do this.

```
library(purrr)

col1 <- c("a1 b1 apple c1","a2 b2 fruit c2","a3 b3 bunny(1) c3","a4 b4 x5  c4")
col2 <- c("b1","b2","b3","b4")
col3 <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4")
col4 <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4")

dat <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)

extract_val <- function(df, input_col, val_cols) {
  # Coerce factors to character. Could omit this if they are already character
  df <- purrr::map_df(df[, c(input_col, val_cols)], as.character)

  # Split the input column on whitespace
  split_col <- strsplit(df[[input_col]], "\\s+")

  # Map over rows, combining the val columns into a list-column of vectors
  temp_df <- purrr::by_row(df[, val_cols], unlist, .collate = "list")

  # Parallel map over the split column and the newly created list-column, and use
  # setdiff to extract the value
  purrr::map2_chr(split_col, temp_df[[".out"]], setdiff)
}

dat$col5 <- extract_val(dat, "col1", c("col2", "col3", "col4"))

dat
##                col1 col2 col3 col4     col5
## 1    a1 b1 apple c1   b1   a1   c1    apple
## 2    a2 b2 fruit c2   b2   a2   c2    fruit
## 3 a3 b3 bunny(1) c3   b3   a3   c3 bunny(1)
## 4      a4 b4 x5  c4   b4   a4   c4       x5
```